# Moving the position of a link in iTextSharp

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating a PDF using iTextSharp that copies the pages from another PDF which works fine. The next requirement was that I make sure that I copy across any internal links as well which I got working with the answer on here:
[Itextsharp: Is There Any Way To Copy Links When Import Pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11022117/itextsharp-is-there-any-way-to-copy-links-when-import-pages)

The problem I have now is that I need to move the position of the link up a bit as the new PDF has a different page height to the original and the links don't line up in the new PDF.

Is there a way of changing the position of a link? I can see the 'urx' property within it but there doesn't seem to be a way of changing it. The only potential option I can find is the TransformRect method but I can't find any documentation on how it works.

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6599734/231316) and [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8141831/231316) which shows how to walk and update links. In those cases we were updating locations but the same ideas should apply.

Comment: Thanks Chris but I don't see how this helps with moving the position of the links within the page?

Comment: Those posts show you how to walk the annotations (which links are a type of), "find" the ones you are looking for and modify their properties via the `Put` method. In your case you'll want to change the `PdfName.RECT` entry (or possibly the PdfName.QUADPOINTS) to what you want. If I had more time I'd whip up a demo but unfortunately I don't.

Comment: Can't use the Put method on PdfName.RECT annotations as that seems to be a PdfArray not PdfDictionary. Tried just assigning a new Rectangle to by doing this: `PdfArray AnnotationRect = (PdfArray)AnnotationDictionary.Get(PdfName.RECT);                    AnnotationRect = new PdfArray(new float[] {100f, 100f, 100f, 100f});` but it didn't change them at all in outputted file